# Tools to analyze Hooks on Windows 7 / 2008, x64 platform

Tags: rootkits

What tool can I use to analyze Hooks (SSDT, Inline etc.) on Windows 7 / 2008? (x64 Platform)

Rku (Rootkit Unhooker) is the only tool I know, which is not available for x64 platforms.

Comment: GMER seems fine and it works on 64 bit machines as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arun suggests, [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/) scans for:

- hidden processes
- hidden threads
- hidden modules
- hidden services
- hidden files
- hidden disk sectors (MBR)
- hidden Alternate Data Streams
- hidden registry keys
- drivers hooking SSDT
- drivers hooking IDT
- drivers hooking IRP calls
- inline hooks

And it also run's fine on x64/x86 machines (currently testing it on my x64)

I haven't tested these but they might help:

- http://www.usec.at/rootkit.html
- http://www.windowsscope.com/